# Whatever happened to Architecture 21015 Eames House?

Tags: sets, architecture

The set was scheduled to be released in 2012, no such luck. Any idea on why it never came out? Was looking forward to building it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to: http://toysnbricks.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=58&t=5288

> so apparently B and N made a mistake, and the Eames House is actually
>   not going to be a set (or so Adam Reed Tucker says). He answered a
>   question about it today at the Master model Builder competition in
>   Chicago

So sad.

Comment: Interesting. Still, considering B&N didn't invent the info, it probably means the set was in development at some point and LEGO did scrap or postpone it. The fact that number 21015 hasn't been attributed (yet?) tends to prove that too. So we still don't know even in which stage of the development process that set was, or really anything that could have happened to it or not within LEGO.

Comment: I appreciate the input. I'll still keep an eye out if it does come out, but, disappointed that my hopes were up for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked the LEGO website out of the same curiosity and they seem to have the Leaning Tower of Pisa for 21015 but they have the image for Sungnyemun 21016 I think they might be updating the page right now. I can't wait to build the Tower of Pisa!